# Responsive HTML + CSS custom break line - IMAGE

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been trying to write a code for this for some time but with no success.

What I want to accomplish:

[image: large screens]

This part isn't hard to do static, but responsive concept gives me nuts.

How should look on small screens:

[image: Small screens display]

How it looks now:

[image]

Like you see, When I start to resize my window it all start good , but then, in one point the right line go to a new line.

**Fiddle:**

I made an example of this on Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Gbcfs/8/

**CODE:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
.line{width:41%; background-color: #a6a6a6; height:1px; display:inline; margin:17px 2px 2px; float:left; min-width:2px;}
 h2 {float:left;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="line"></div>
<h2>How it works</h2>
<div class="line"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with a border.

Try this:

```
  <h2><span>Heading 2</span></h2>


body {
  background-color:#fff;
}
h2 {
  border-bottom:solid 1 px black;
  text-align:center;
}
h2 span {
  background-color:#fff;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  margin-bottom:-3px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/aguxoz/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem have dependancy on font-size too,
try with the following CSS

```
<style>
.line{width:30%; background: #a6a6a6  0 50% repeat-x; display:inline; margin:2px 2px 2px; float:left; }
 h2 {float:left;}
.autowidth
 {
    width:auto;
 }
 </style>
```

along with the follwoing mark-up

```
<div class="autowidth">
<div class="line"></div>
<h2>How it works</h2>
<div class="line"></div>
<div>
```

This can help to an extent.

Comment: background-repeat is for images

Comment: Hey NBaua! Tnx for contributing.. I find previous answer as more organized so I will mark it as an answer.. Tnx again..

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code ........... i think this is very helpful..

```
<div><div class="line"></div>
<h2 style="padding-top:8px">How it works</h2>
<div class="line"></div></div>
```

```
.line{width:41%; background-color: #a6a6a6; height:1px; display:inline; margin:17px 2px 0 2px; float:left; min-width:2px;}
h2 {float:left;}
```